# Error installing apache with msiexec

Tags: windows, apache, windows-installer

When installing httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8y.msi with command:

```
msiexec /i apache.msi INSTALLDIR=c:\apache
```

all works ok. With the command

```
msiexec /i apache.msi INSTALLDIR=c:\apache \qn
```

It breaks. It appears the apache monitor, but the service its not in there. Same with \qb and \quiet

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work with

```
msiexec /i apache.msi /passive ALLUSERS=1 SERVERADMIN=admin@localhost SERVERNAME=localhost SERVERDOMAIN=localhost SERVERPORT=80 INSTALLDIR=c:\apache
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  This just got me through my quiet install error.